# Why is this algorithm O(N)?

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o

The following C code is apparently O(N) (according to my practice exam). However, I am not sure as to why it is O(N) and not O(Something*Something).

```
void doit(int N) {
    while (N) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j += 1) {
        }
        N = N / 2;  
    }
}
```

Anyone care to give me some insight to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because N + N/2 + N/4 + ... = 2N.

Comment: Many thanks! Should have paid attention in series haha

Comment: @user2109258 It's actually a famous series, think of  a man and his dog, they both are going to the same place together, the dog moves at twice the speed of the man, so when the dog reaches the target, he comes back to the man and when the dog gets back to the man, he goes back to their target and so on, until the man reaches the target, the question is **what is the total distance traveled by the dog**?