# Understanding time complexity, big-O notation

Tags: python, function, big-o, complexity-theory

Edit- this question is from a former test in my course, the official answer is `O(n)`

I need help understanding why does the run-time complexity in the following code is `O(n)` and not `O(n*log(n))`

```
def fun(n):
   total = 0
   while n > 5:
       n = n // 2
       total += sum(range(n))
   return total
```

The while loop executes `log(n)` times, and in each iteration the sum function sums `n/2` numbers, therefore it's complexity is `o(n)`, I see that each `while` iteration there's less numbers to sum, but i don't understand why it's `O(n)`.

Thank you.

Comment: As written, it is `O(n log n)`, I think, but if you were to substitute the closed form `n * (n - 1) / 2` for `sum(range(n))` then it would go down to `O(log n)`, for the reason you mention. Maybe the person who's telling you it's `O(n)` is misunderstanding the while loop as being linear?

Comment: For what it's worth technically `sum(range(n))` can be computed in `O(1)` since it has a closed form solution.

Comment: @CoryKramer does python computes it that way?

Comment: This is a dupe of many questions, but the answer is because  n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... is less than 2n.

Comment: It's essentially a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761284/why-is-this-algorithm-on/29761325#29761325 although that code is in C and stops when n is 0 rather than 5.

Comment: @MadaBit `range(n)` returns a range object which exposes properties for start, stop, step ... so you could write your own sum implementation to take advantage of that - AFAICT builtin `sum` does not though https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured it out.

Each `while` iteration sums `n/2` items. which means total iterations are `n\2 + n\4 +n\8 +...`, and this sum converges to `n`